# What is Reference(fluent nhibernate) Equivllent in EF Fluent?

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate, entity-framework-5

I am converting from nhibernate to EF 5.0 as I want to see if it will make my life easier(having way too many problems with the Spatial 3rd library)

What is the equivalents for these fluent nhibernate mappings

```
References
HasMany
HasManyToMany
HasOne
```

I am using separate files(`EntityTypeConfiguration`) like I would with nhibernate fluent instead of putting it all with the db context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620

Instead of modelBuilder.Entity() use "this".

BTW. I know you're coming from nHibernate, but much of EF magic comes from conventions. Yeah, you can specified everything if config files, but why not try conventions first? Saying that if you work on some big, huge, finance project then may stick to configs.

Oh, and this may be confusing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor)
    .WithOptional(t => t.OfficeAssignment);
```

It works like that:
OfficeAssignement has required Instructor, after this call you are at instructor, so instructor has optional OfficeAssignement. I found this confusing when I started with EF

Comment: What do you mean comes from conventions? I am doing the mapping because I want to specify how long my columns and stuff should be. Yes I found that confusing when I saw that when I got my mapping generated by the entity power tools.

Comment: Oh, I meant relationwise, if it's many to many, just create classes with Lists and EF will figure this out and create many-to-many mapping by itself. Regarding how long the columns should be you could use StringLenght annotation. I use EF to speed up development for start ups that need its cost as low as possible. Hence, creating  configuration class for each class would be an overkill for me. But as I said, if you work on some serious project then you may want to invest that time.

Comment: Well I am more use to fluent mapping and find it cleaner but I guess I can just map out what I need to change right and let EF figure out the rest?

Comment: This is what I do. It really speeds up development. But bear in mind that every EF book will say don't mix fluent API and attributes (I don't agree with that unless one has over 50 tables). I think you should try new approach and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean mix attributes. I thought you said that EF can figure out the relationships itself. So I might need to make the Name Property a length of 500 and that is all I change in the fluent config

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was carried out with using attributes. Yes, that's the best approach use convention as much as possible, saves you a lot of time. And if you need specific behaviour use configuration. And yes, in most cases EF can figure out the relations by itself. In a few others you will have to use FluentAPI.

Comment: As I said I ran it though the EF powertools and it makes the FK from the tables as properties. I guessing that is not really needed right?

Comment: No, no, leave foreign key properties as part of POCO! They are very useful for deleting entities without loading them from db. There is convention for foreign keys that saves you time. If you have a property User then int UserID will be recognized as FK for User, so it's Entity+ID. You may use any name for foreign key, but then you need attributes or fluentAPI.

Comment: If the fk ids do I have to put them as IsRequired as well as the mapping of the references?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29214/discussion-between-mariusz-w-and-chobo2)